# What do these excerpts from El Lazarillo de Tormes mean?

Tags: traducción

Context of the sentence:

> Con el tiempo, mi madre me dio un hermanito negro. Era muy bonito y yo jugaba con él y ayudaba a cuidarle. **Mi hermanito nos veía a mi madre y a mí muy blancos y a su padre no, por eso le tenía miedo.** Recuerdo que una vez estaba mi padrastro jugando con él y el pequeño se escapaba diciendo: —¡Mamá, el coco!

1- What does seeing someone as white mean?

> ¡Probablemente en el mundo hay muchas personas que tienen miedo de los demás porque **no se ven a ellos mismos**!

2- Does `no se ven a ellos mismos` mean they are afraid of others because they are different?

> Cuando sintió que mi cabeza estaba cerca de la piedra, me dio un gran golpe en el **toro**.

3- Does `toro` here mean crotch, butt, head or something else?

Comment: Hello. You have already some experience on this site and you have been posting questions for a while. Remember that we don't really do bulk translating. I posted an answer explaining what I think you need to know in order to understand those paragraphs, but in order to get the most of this site, you might want to be more specific about what is causing you trouble. Please, avoid asking for plain translations. Also, don't hesitate to ask several questions if needed (here all comes from the same source text, but the third paragraph-question is much less related to the others than the first two)

Comment: I do research before asking, I don't post anything that's inconclusive. 1st I search in reverse context from 100s of sources in multiple databases (reverso, linguee), then compare machine translations from 5 different sites (not too hard b/c I wrote a script to do the work for me-which I can post if anyone wants. Highlight pronounce, conjugate, define, in context with a button). Then I check on pure translation sites. Evidence https://www.reddit.com/r/translation/comments/5pybu2/spanishenglishmi_hermanito_nos_ve%C3%ADa_a_mi_madre_y/. Finally here if i ask here if I don't get a good answer.

Comment: Hi. Please don't feel like we are scolding you or telling you off for a bad post. I have been in your situation myself and I know it is upsetting. It is not actually about governance of the site or "rules", it is really about how to make it much easier for others to help you. We actually try to explain how questions could be improved, and even if they get closed (which doesn't mean they could be re-opened after proper editing) here you don't get heavily downvoted as in other stacks. If/when this happens to you again feel free to ask "what is unclear/wrong with my question?" and get some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"El coco" es uno de esos monstruos del folklore con los que se austa a los niños. Es como "el hombre del saco".

> Si no te terminas la cena, vendrá *el coco* y te llevará.
>
> "Duérmete niño, duérmete ya...
>
> Que viene el Coco y te comerá."  <sub>canción de cuna</sub>

La referencia aparece incluso en la entrada de "[coco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9bCoA8r%7C9bH8Cra%7C9bIHCql%7C9bJM96n)" en la RAE:

> de *coco*, porque la cáscara del fruto con sus tres agujeros semeja una cabeza con ojos y boca, **como la de aquel fantasma infantil**.

Según [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coco_(folklore)), el mito se originó en Portugal y Galicia y "coco" deriva de "coca" (*"acocado"* en portugués viene a significar "niño malcriado").

Así que en el primer párrafo entiendo que la madre del narrador tuvo un hijo con un negro. El niño (que sería *mulato*) veía a la madre ya al narrador de piel blanca, pero a su padre (padrastro del narrador) negro y eso le daba miedo, porque pensaba que era "el coco".

> ¡Probablemente en el mundo hay muchas personas que tienen miedo de los demás porque **no se ven a ellos mismos**!

La parte en negrita no significa que les den miedo porque sean diferentes. La gracia está en que ese niño mulato tenía miedo del padre porque era negro, pero él mismo era mulato (mestizo de ancestros negros y blancos). Si el niño se hubiera mirado en un espejo, habría dicho "ey, ese tío es mucho más negro que mamá y mis hermanos... pero yo también soy mucho más oscurito!!". Así que la connotación de esa frase es más bien "si se vieran a sí mismos no tendrían tanto miedo de otros por ser diferentes, ya que no los verían tan diferentes de sí mismos".

Para la tercera frase, te falta contexto. El narrador está viendo una estatua de un toro. El ciego del Lazarillo de Tormes, que es un *cabronazo*, le dice a Lázaro que acerque la cabeza a la estatua, para oír cómo la estatua hace ruido como un todo de verdad. Luego le golpea contra la estatua y se ríe de él por ser tan ingenuo. Cuando Lázaro dice "me dio un golpe en el toro" quiere decir que el ciego le golpeó *contra* la estatua del toro.

> Cuando [el ciego] sintió que mi cabeza estaba cerca de la piedra [la estatua del toro], me dio un gran golpe en **ella** [en la estatua del toro]

Comment: ¡Qué interesante! No sabía lo del Coco en castellano, solo en asturianu "Dúrmite neñu míu que'l cocu vien / A llevar los neñinos que poco durmen al run run"  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Fii_F1GIFY  Ya ves las curiosidades de los extranjeros que aprenden estas cosas de solo una región

Comment: Your analysis here was great! I can read something over and over, and never figure out what it means.